# How to add 3px margin between bootstrap cols

Tags: css, margins, bootstrap-grid

I want to add some space between blocks. I am using bootstrap grid system.

whem I add margin the third div gets down under block 1.

below is my code:

[image]

```
<div style='border:solid black 1px' class='col-md-6'>
  <h1>Block 1</h1>
</div>
<div style='border:solid black 1px' class='col-md-3'>
  <h1>Block 2</h1>
</div>
<div style='border:solid black 1px' class='col-md-3'>
  <h1>Block 3</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: add mr-1 or ml-1 bootstrap margin utility classes to the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the [`col-md`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options) class and eventually an [`mx-md-1`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) class or set margin yourself .

here is an example *to run in full page to resize & see breakpoints effect*  :

```css
.row {/* for demo to show where is center & where it stands */
  border: solid;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #4564 50%, #0008 50%)
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div style='border:solid black 1px' class=' col-md-6 '>
      <h1>Block 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div style='border:solid black 1px' class='  col-md mx-md-1'>
      <h1>Block 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div style='border:solid black 1px' class='  col-md-3 '>
      <h1>Block 3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`col/col-sm/col-md/col-lg/col-xl` classes will use the space avalaible without setting a width, only a breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You can add spacing between columns in Bootstrap's Grid system by using the [Offset classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns), like so with your example:

```
<div style='border:solid black 1px' class='col-md-7'>
  <h1>Block 1</h1>
</div>
<div style='border:solid black 1px' class='col-md-3 offset-md-1'>
  <h1>Block 2</h1>
</div>
<div style='border:solid black 1px' class='col-md-3 offset-md-1'>
  <h1>Block 3</h1>
</div>
```

Though you can't pick the exact pixel amounts for that spacing, you have to settle for Bootstrap's units (from 1 to 12 at the end of the class).